# How to make Tomcat on AWS EC2 available from outside localhost

Tags: tomcat, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to run Tomcat on an AWS Linux server.  I've installed Tomcat, and tested it from the command line to make sure it's working, but I can't access it from another machine.  The details:

1. The instance has port 80 incoming for HTTP open in the security group.
2. I have verified that it's running on port 80 by telnetting into localhost on that port and doing a GET request.
3. I tried adding the public DNS as an alias for localhost in server.xml then restarting to make sure the changes are picked up.

Yet if I try to access it via my browser (outside the actual server) using the public DNS I get "could not connect".

Any ideas?

Thanks...

Comment: Have you tried connecting to external IP rather than via DNS?

Comment: I did.  I associated it with an Elastic IP and tried that, with no success.

Comment: OK, the probably turned out to be that I also needed to edit and restart iptables, as explained here: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-rhel-linux-open-port-using-iptables/

Comment: @Nickchase post your solution as the answer - it helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, the problem turned out to be that I also needed to edit and restart iptables, as explained here: http://cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-rhel-linux-open-port-using-iptables

Answer (score 5):

Adding what is not mentioned in above answers.

For me, allowing `TCP over 8080` was missing.
So, I have created new Inbound rule with following details:

- Type : Custom TCP Rule
- Protocol : TCP
- Port Range : 8080
- Source : Anywhere

This worked for me.
Hope it may help someone. :)

Comment: This worked, I was searching for this answer for past 2hrs

Answer (score 0):

did you open the 80 port?

when you create your instance, you select a security group for it.

go to security groups on the left side, clic to the group of your instance and downside, at inbound tab, you set:

- create a new rule: HTTP
- Source: 0.0.0.0/0

clic to add rule and clic to apply rule changes.

thats it

Comment: No, unfortunately, that's not it. :(  That DOES need to be done, but it's not ALL that needs to be done.  Thanks, though!

Comment: if you are on windows (i know original question was for linux), don't forget to turn off the windows firewall

Answer (score 0):

I have tried everything as mentioned in the post and as I found out, my tomcat was using IPv6 instead of IPv4, I modified that too by 
editing /etc/sysctl.conf with following config changes:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1 
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1 
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

After saving, I ran the "sudo sysctl -p" command to reload sysctl. It changed the IPv6 to IPv4 after restarting tomcat. Verified by

(Before)
    $ sudo lsof -i:8080 -n

```
COMMAND  PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    4224 tomcat   46u  IPv6  15733      0t0  TCP *:webcache (LISTEN)
```

(After) $ sudo lsof -i:8080 -n

```
COMMAND  PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    4414 tomcat   46u  IPv4  16364      0t0  TCP *:webcache (LISTEN)
```

I hope this helps someone facing a similar issue!